# How to a make Ajax for html() call work in D3.js .html()

Tags: jquery, ajax, d3.js

I modified some d3.js code to load content on the page. But I am having trouble getting part of the code to load some being loaded by ajax call.  I like to load it using D3.js .html() method instead of it being loaded using the ajax call method (variables and jquery .html() call inside the ajax call).

The ajax method works, but I think moving the variables and the jQuery elements outside the ajax will make the code more efficient. I provided my sample code which works via ajax call below.  I commented out my tries using the d3.js method.

```
d3.csv('data.csv', function(error, data){
    if (error){
         alert("Data didn't load, Refresh your browser");
 
     }else{

var container = gallery.selectAll('.imgContainer')  
    .filter(function(d) { return d.id;})
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.id;  })
         
container.enter()
        .append('div')
        .filter(function(d) { return d != 'null' })
        .attr('class',function(d) { return  'imgContainer imgContainer' + d.id});
        
container.selectAll('.picture')
    .data(function(d) { return [d]; })
    .enter()
    .append("a")
    .attr('class',function(d) { return  'fancybox'})
    .attr("rel","data-fancybox data-width='640'data-height='360'")
    .attr("href",function(d) {return '/Creative/Shared%20Documents/podcast/audio/'+ d.sampleImagesVideo})
    .attr("data-fancybox",function(d) {return  d.groupVideo})
    .attr("title", function(d) {return  d.messageVideo})
    .append('img')
    .attr("class", function(d) { return  "picture picture" + d.id})
    .attr('width', "100%")
    .attr('height', "auto") 
    .style("display", "inline-block")
    //.attr("href",function(d) {return '/Creative/Shared%20Documents/podcast/audio/'+ d.imgsrcVideo;})
    .attr('src', function(d) { return '/Creative/Shared%20Documents/podcast/graphics/'+ d.imgsrcVideo; })/**/
    .on("click", function(d) {
         console.log("clicked" + d.id); 
         updateData("Field-" + d.id);
    });

container.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))             
        .attr("y", 0 - (300 / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "14px") 
        .style("color", "black")
        .style("word-wrap", "break-word")
        .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
        .html(function(d) { return d.imageTitleVideo.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""); });
        
container.append("div")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return  "views" + d.id})
    //.html("Views: " + views + data)
    //.html(function(d) { return "Views: " + views})
        }
    })
});



function updateData(viewhit) {
    var restendpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ViewsTest')/items";
    $.ajax({
        url: restendpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            __metadata: {
                type: "SP.Data.ViewsTestListItem"
            },
            Title: "Podcast",
            Views: viewhit
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("Item added to the SharePoint list");
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error Occurred!");
        }
    });
}
/**/

//////Add count to card div
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        $.ajax({
                   url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ViewsTest')/items",
                   method: "GET",
                   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                   success: function (data) {
                        
                        if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                                var views =0;
                                var views10 =0;
                                var views9 =0;
                                var views8 =0;
                                var views7 =0;
                                var views6 =0;
                                var views5 =0;
                                var views4 =0;
                                var views3 =0;
                                var views2 =0;
                                var views1 =0;
                                
                               data.d.results.forEach(function(item){
                                                
                                    /*For expansion*/
                                    if(item.Views === "Field-10")
                                      views10++;
                                    if(item.Views  === "Field-9")
                                      views9++;
                                    if(item.Views  === "Field-8")
                                      views8++;
                                    if(item.Views === "Field-7")
                                      views7 += 1;
                                    if(item.Views  === "Field-6")
                                      views6++;
                                    if(item.Views  === "Field-5")//pending post
                                      views5++;
                                    if(item.Views === "Field-4")
                                      views4++;
                                    if(item.Views  === "Field-3")
                                      views3++;
                                    if(item.Views  === "Field-2")
                                      views2++;
                                    if(item.Views  === "Field-1")
                                      views1++;
                                }); 
                        }
                        /**/
                        $("#views10").html("Views: " + views10);
                        $("#views9").html("Views: " + views9);
                        $("#views8").html("Views: " + views8);
                        $("#views7").html("Views: " + views7);
                        $("#views6").html("Views: " + views6);
                        $("#views5").html("Views: " + views5);
                        $("#views4").html("Views: " + views4);
                        $("#views3").html("Views: " + views3);
                        $("#views2").html("Views: " + views2);
                        $("#views1").html("Views: " + views1);
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      alert("Error: "+ data);
                 }
          });
  });////Close of Document Ready Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.select('#views-' + id)` on the `container` variable to select the count labels.

However, at the moment your code contains a race condition:

1. The count labels are drawn by d3 after `d3.csv('data.csv', ...)` has loaded the items for the gallery asynchronously.
2. At the same time, you are fetching the view counts by ajax from SharePoint (inside `jQuery(document).ready()`).

When (2) resolves, you are using jquery to access the DOM created in (1). But there is *no* way to guarantee that (1) is executed before (2).

**Sequential Calls**

Wrap the call to SharePoint in to a promise.

```
const getViewCountsFromSharePoint = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ajax call to SharePoint
    $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(data) {
        // data looks something like this: [{Views: 'Field-1'}, {Views: 'Field-2'}, {Views: 'Field-3'}, {Views: 'Field-2'}, {Views: 'Field-3'}];
        // use dictionary for the item count
        const views = data.reduce((dictionary, item) => {
          if (dictionary[item.Views]) {
            dictionary[item.Views] = dictionary[item.Views] + 1;
          } else {
            dictionary[item.Views] = 1;
          }

          return dictionary;
       }, {});

       resolve(views);
     },
     error: reject
   })
};
```

Then make the Ajax call right after `d3.csv()` is loaded. That way you have the full data loaded *before* any rendering.

```
 d3.csv('data.csv', function(error, data) {
   if (error) { /* throw error */ }
   // load the initial view counts from SP
   getViewCountsFromSharePoint()
     .then(function(viewsDictionary) {
       var container = gallery.selectAll('.imgContainer')
       ...
       container
         .append('img')
         ...
         .on('click', (event, d) => {
           // use d3.select instead of jQuery
           const countLabel = container.select('#views-' + d.id);
           // increment the label
           const beforeCount = parseInt(countLabel.html());
           const afterCount = beforeCount + 1;
          
           // update the SharePoint list
           updateData("Field-" + d.id)

           countLabel.html(afterCount);
         });

       container.append("div")
         .attr("id", function(d) { return  "views" + d.id})
         .html(d => {
           // 'd' is the original data array
           // create the key to the dictionary
           const viewsKey = 'Field-' + d.id;
           const numberOfViewsForItem = viewsDictionary[viewsKey] ? viewsDictionary[viewsKey] : 0;
           return numberOfViewsForItem;
         })
     })      
 })
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph, the script looks good.  I'm trying but I get data is not a function at this part of the provided script and I can't seem to fix.  Any ideas?
const views = data((dictionary, item) => {
          if (dictionary[item.Views]) {
            dictionary[item.Views] = dictionary[item.Views] + 1;
          } else {
            dictionary[item.Views] = 1;
          }

          return dictionary;
       }, {});

       resolve(views);
     },
     error: reject
   })
};

Comment: I made some progress.  I corrected the above issue by changing data with var views = data.d.results.forEach(function(dictionary, item){.  Things are running to the next error. Now I'm getting an error in the D3 HTML function, viewsDictionary[viewsKey] with error reading, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: viewsDictionary is undefined.  Why the Promise,  getViewCountsFromSharePoint().then(function(viewsDictionary) { reads undefined?

Comment: I am sorry Tony. I made a mistake in typing out the answer. I use data.reduce() to turn the SharePoint response into a dictionary with the Views string as a key. I edited my answer. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Not a problem Christoph.  I really appreciate your help.  I added the update script and I got this error:  Uncaught TypeError: data.reduce is not a function.  Any ideas?

Comment: data should be an array of the items returned from the SP list: [{Views: 'Field-1'}, {Views: 'Field-2'}, {Views: 'Field-3'}, {Views: 'Field-2'}, {Views: 'Field-3'}]. data.reduce() should return a dictionary which looks like {
    "Field-1": 1,
    "Field-2": 2,
    "Field-3": 2
}. Basically the field key ("Field-2") with a total count. Can you confirm that data is an array?